# PHP preg_replace is Not working in multi line

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove the "-" character at the end of every line:

```
$text = "abc - xyz

abc-

-xyz
";
```

It is not producing the desired result as of now.

I am using the following PHP:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\-$/m", "*", $text);
```

The desired result:

```
$text = "abc - xyz

abc*

-xyz
";
```

or a similar solution.

Comment: define "not working" - what is the result you're _getting_?

Comment: nothing happen, but its replace end of text "-" but i want end of line

Comment: It *does* work, it replaces every `-` that is the last character of a line with a star. What do you expect?

Comment: i tried many times still not working

<?php
$text = "abc - xyz

abc-

-xyz
";

$text = preg_replace("/\-$/m", "*", $text);

echo $text;

?>

Comment: Here is my guess https://regex101.com/r/xbm7eT/1/ this isn't what your example has though. Also `-` is only a special character in character classes, it doesn't need to be escaped in this usage.

Comment: There's probably an horizontal whitespace between the trailing hyphen and the end of the line. Try with `/-+\h*$/mu`

Comment: does not work please another solution

Comment: Copying and pasting your code verbatim works as expected. https://3v4l.org/SM4Zm Chances are that what you've pasted here is not actually representative of the actual input you're running code against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "abc - xyz

abc-

-xyz


123-

---s---

--sss
";


$text = preg_replace("/\-\r$/m", "\r", $text);

echo $text;
```

**Yields**

```
abc - xyz

abc

-xyz


123

---s--

--sss
```

Comment: oh!! ya.. catch that point its a '\r' in hidden so its not changing. thanks

Comment: Please "*" to "*\r"

Comment: Change to $text = preg_replace("/\-\r$/m", "*", $text);
Missing $.
after i accept answer

Comment: I added the $ to preg_replace

Comment: Please "*" to "*\r" return \r

Comment: Now the trailing - is completely removed.

Answer (score 2):

This simple expression is likely to replace the undesired dashes with a `*`:

```
$re = '/-+$/m';
$str = 'abc - xyz
abc-
-xyz
abc - xyz
abc-abc-abc-abc----
-xyz';
$subst = '*';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

```
abc - xyz
abc*
-xyz
abc - xyz
abc-abc-abc-abc*
-xyz
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pl0hC3/1/) if you wish to explore.

Comment: No please try PHP preg_replace

Comment: i used with php 5.6

Comment: sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com try